# Can "geology" be used as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

I have to translate a national agency from my native language into English.

I have 3 options, as follows:

National Geological Agency

Geological Agency of country X

National Geology Agency

My question: Can "geology" be used as adjective, "geological"?

Comment: There's also "National Agency of Geology"...

Answer (score 1):

The title of such an agency is usually expressed as

> the National Geological Agency

some governmental geological agencies are referred to as

> the **National Geological Survey**
>   US Geological Survey
>   French Geological Survey
>   British Geological Survey
>   China Geological Survey

If the agency's mission is to share learned research is is usually referred to as a **Society**

> the National Geological Society *(of)*

Comment: If it's governmental, I wouldn't use "society" instead of "agency"... they serve different purposes.